# How to input a list into a Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, model

I am pretty new to using tensowflow and keras.
I have an x_train and y_train set of the form

```
x_train = [[ 21   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [ 22   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [ 23   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [255   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [256   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [257   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]

y_train = [4 1 1 1 4 1 3 1 2 4 4 1 1 4 4 4 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 1 4 1 4 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 4
3 4 1 1 4 3 1 4 4 1 4 1 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 1 4 1 3 4 4 1 4 1 2 1 4
4 1 1 4 1 4 4 3 4 1 3 1 1 3 1 4 2 4 2 2 1 4 3 1 1 4 2 1 3 1 4 4 1 3 4 4 1
1 1 3 3 4 1 4 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 4 1 1 3 4 1 2 4 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 1 4 1 4 4 4 4 1
1 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 1 4 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 4 1 1
1 4 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 1 3 4 3 4 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 4 3 4 2 1 4 4 1
4 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 4 4 4 1 4 1 2 4 1 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 4 1 4
1 1 4 4]
```

How do I feed this into a model.

I have tried this after following a tutorial online. But it doesnt seem to take in list input

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Provide further details like context, x and y shapes and if possible the values for x and y (not output). Also add the error message for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the x_train & y_train lists by converting them into a Numpy array .
Here is the code for your reference :

```
x_train = np.random.random((1100, 2))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1100,1))

X_train = np.vstack([x_train, x_train])
Y_train = np.vstack([y_train, y_train])

print(X_train.shape)        
print(Y_train.shape)
```

Output :

```
(2200, 2)
(2200, 1)
```

Model
Building :

```
Inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2, ))
hidden1 = Dense(units=100, activation="sigmoid")(Inputs)
hidden2 = Dense(units=100, activation='relu')(hidden1)
predictions = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)

model = tf.keras.Model([Inputs], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=5)
```

Output :

```
Epoch 1/5
220/220 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7016 - accuracy: 0.5005
Epoch 2/5
220/220 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7011 - accuracy: 0.5064
Epoch 3/5
220/220 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7005 - accuracy: 0.4868
Epoch 4/5
220/220 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6999 - accuracy: 0.5082
Epoch 5/5
220/220 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6986 - accuracy: 0.5155
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9a6b9e2230>
```